# Add foreign key to existing table using EF core

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-3.1

I have *HomeSetting* table with duplicate *HomeIds* and I want to remove it by setting the foreign key as well.

```cs
public class Home
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR(200)")]
    public string HomeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR(200)")]
    public string HomeName { get; set; } 
}

public class HomeSetting
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR(200)")]
    public string HomeId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR(MAX)")]
    public string Settings { get; set; }
}
```

I added [ForeignKey("Home")] attribute to *HomeSetting*'s table HomeId column but it doesn't work.
How do i mange this using ef core migration ?

```cs
[ForeignKey("Home")]
public string HomeId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Class Home.Id is int . where HomeId in home settings is string ?.

Comment: @AvinashReddy  there is Id and  HomeId columns in Home table

Comment: I think you need to define Home class in HomeSetting.

Answer (score 0):

You must use key for foreign key and cant use property for foreign key.
In this moment we have two way:

1. Use HomeId as a key
2. Use both of them for key

actually first way is simple I write second way:

1. Create classes

```
        public class Home
        {
           [Key]
           public int Id { get; set; }
    
           [Required]
           [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR(200)")]
           public string HomeId { get; set; }
    
           [Required]
           [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR(200)")]
           public string HomeName { get; set; }
    
           public HomeSetting HomeSetting { get; set; }
        }


        public class HomeSetting
        {
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int Id { get; set; }
    
            [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR(200)")]
            public string HomeId { get; set; }
    
            public int HomeIntId { get; set; }
    
            [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR(MAX)")]
            public string Settings { get; set; }
    
    
            public Home Home { get; set; }
        }
```

2. Create mapping class

```
        public class HomeMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Home>
        {
                public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Home> builder)
                {
                    builder.HasKey(x => new { x.Id, x.HomeId});
    
                    builder.HasOne(x => x.HomeSetting)
                        .WithOne(x => x.Home)
                        .HasForeignKey<HomeSetting>(x => new {x.HomeIntId, x.HomeId });
               }
        }
```

3. Override `OnModelCreateing` method in DBContext

```
          protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
          {
              base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
              modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new HomeMap());
          }
```